# Simple Banking Application - Deposit and Withdrawing (Using Abstract & Constructors) (JAVA)

Tags: java, constructor, switch-statement, java.util.scanner, abstract

I need help to figure out how to fix my code. I am trying to allow for money to be deposited and withdrawn in a bank using a menu. What happens is that when ever i go through the depositing or withdrawing options, the values do not get stored and just reset as the loop starts again. I want to be able to add balance or be takeout balance (sort of like an actual bank would). In this code i am using 2 classes (Minibank & Function). Does anyone know what i can do to fix this problem? (Sorry for the messy code)

```
import java.util.*; //import everything
import java.lang.*;
public class MiniBank extends Function {

public static void main(String[] args) {             
Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);

int menu = 3;

        do{          

        System.out.println("1:Deposit");
        System.out.println("2:Withdraw");
        System.out.println("3:Check Balance");
        System.out.println("4:Exit");


              switch (menu){
            case 1:
             Function Deposit = new Function() {};; 
                Deposit.Deposit(ask);  
                break;
            case 2:
               Function Withdraw = new Function() {};; 
                Withdraw.Withdraw(ask);
                break;

            case 3:
                Function Howmuch = new Function() {};; 
                Howmuch.Money();
                break;   

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                System.exit(0);    
        }     
       System.out.println("Select Following Options");

       menu=ask.nextInt(); //menu option
       }while (menu!=4);              
        }
}
```

```
import java.util.*;
abstract public class Function{ 
protected double Balance;


public Function(){ 
    //going to add something later
}
public void Deposit(Scanner ask){
    System.out.println("Insert the amount put in");
    double task = ask.nextDouble();
    Balance = Balance + task;
    System.out.println("Account balance: "+ Balance);

}
public void Withdraw(Scanner ask){
    System.out.println("Insert the amount to take out");
    double task = ask.nextDouble();
    Balance = Balance - task;
    System.out.println("Account balance: "+ Balance);
}
public void Money(){
    System.out.println(Balance);
}
}
```

Comment: `new Function() {};;` is creating **new** instances (through an anonymous subclass). Why are you doing that?

Comment: i was doing that to call the function.

Comment: "Nothing" wrong with the code, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do. The issue is within the logic. As @ElliottFrisch mentioned, what you're doing is creating a new instance of that class, thus resetting the values.
Instantiate the `Function` class outside of the loop

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a new "Bank" (Function) for each case of your `switch`. Also, you should be creating a Bank. Something like,

```
MiniBank mb = new MiniBank();
do {
    // ...
    switch (menu) {
    case 1:
        mb.Deposit(ask);
        break;
    case 2:
        mb.Withdraw(ask);
        break;
    case 3:
        mb.Money();
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        System.exit(0);
    }
// ...
```

Also, by convention, Java method names should start with lowercase letters (your methods look like classes).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `Function` everytime which means you aren't reusing the balance field declared in `Function`. You can fix it only using one instance of `Minibank` like this:

```
import java.util.*; //import everything
import java.lang.*;
public class MiniBank extends Function {

public static void main(String[] args) {             
Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);

Minibank bank = new Minibank(); // This is your object used for depositing and withdrawing

int menu = 3;

        do{          

        System.out.println("1:Deposit");
        System.out.println("2:Withdraw");
        System.out.println("3:Check Balance");
        System.out.println("4:Exit");


              switch (menu){
            case 1: 
                bank.Deposit(ask);  
                break;
            case 2:
                bank.Withdraw(ask);
                break;

            case 3: 
                bank.Money();
                break;   

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                System.exit(0);    
        }     
       System.out.println("Select Following Options");

       menu=ask.nextInt(); //menu option
       }while (menu!=4);              
        }
}
```